# Using ParseFacebookUtils to login android app with facebook

Tags: android, facebook, null, facebook-login

I am working on an application that uses Parse and I want to login using Facebook.

This is my code:

```
        Button facebook = (Button)findViewById(R.id.facebook);
    facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(signUpStep2.this, new LogInCallback() {
                  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err){
                      if (user == null) {Log.d("My app", "NULL");}
 }                    else if (user.isNew()){Log.d("My app", "New User");}
                      else{Log.d("My app", "User");}
```

However, I am always getting a Null user, and a Null ParseException err.

What is my error?

Answer (score 0):

try to set permission on login method.
you can also check these links: [Android Facebook login returns null user](https://parse.com/questions/android-facebook-login-returns-null-user-and-null-err) and [ParseFacebookUtils.LogIn I keep getting a null ParseUser object](https://parse.com/questions/parsefacebookutilslogin-i-keep-getting-a-null-parseuser-object)

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(Arrays.asList("email",Permissions.Friends.ABOUT_ME,Permissions.Friends.BIRTHDAY),
            this, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {
                Log.d("My app", "NULL");
            } else if (user.isNew()) {
                Log.d("My app", "New User");                
            } else {
                Log.d("My app", "User");
            }
        } 
    });
```